# Why HTTP 403 when saving config in Jenkins Configure Clouds?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

### How I Replicate the Issue

- Log in from the Jenkins Dashboard
- Go to *Manage Jenkins* > *Configure Nodes and Clouds* > *Configure Clouds*
- Update the configuration (optional, since issue is present without modifying anything)
- Click either "Save" or "Apply"

### Result

**Jenkins Web UI:**

[image]

I tried to inspect the logs:

- `/var/log/jenkins/audit.log` — no logs during relevant timeframe.
- `journalctl -u jenkins.service` — nothing relevant.
- `/var/log/jenkins/access_log` (trimmed to relevant timeframe only):

  ```plaintext
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:21:59 +0800] "GET /jenkins/manage/configureClouds/ HTTP/1.1" 403 631 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/   manage/computer/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:00 +0800] "GET /jenkins/login HTTP/1.1" 200 643 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/   configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  10.203.40.50 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:16 +0800] "GET /jenkins/login HTTP/1.1" 200 619 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:16 +0800] "POST /jenkins/j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/   login?from=%2Fjenkins%2Fmanage%2FconfigureClouds%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)    Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:17 +0800] "GET /jenkins/adjuncts/4674b761/org/kohsuke/stapler/bind.js HTTP/1.1" 200 936 "https://   sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/   108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:17 +0800] "GET /jenkins/manage/configureClouds/ HTTP/1.1" 200 96523 "https://sub.domain.com/   jenkins/login?from=%2Fjenkins%2Fmanage%2FconfigureClouds%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like    Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:17 +0800] "GET /jenkins/adjuncts/4674b761/jenkins/views/JenkinsHeader/search-box.js HTTP/1.1" 200    147 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like    Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:17 +0800] "GET /jenkins/adjuncts/4674b761/lib/layout/breadcrumbs.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2750 "https://   sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/   108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:18 +0800] "GET /jenkins/adjuncts/4674b761/lib/form/filter-menu-button/filter-menu-button.js HTTP/1.   1" 200 747 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,    like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:18 +0800] "GET /jenkins/adjuncts/4674b761/lib/form/hetero-list/hetero-list.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2136    "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like    Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:18 +0800] "GET /jenkins/adjuncts/4674b761/lib/form/repeatable/repeatable.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2594    "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like    Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:19 +0800] "GET /jenkins/adjuncts/4674b761/lib/form/select/select.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1825 "https://   sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/   108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:19 +0800] "GET /jenkins/adjuncts/4674b761/lib/form/advanced/advanced.js HTTP/1.1" 200 703 "https://   sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/   108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:19 +0800] "GET /jenkins/adjuncts/4674b761/lib/form/validateButton/adjunct.js HTTP/1.1" 200 133    "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like    Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:20 +0800] "GET /jenkins/adjuncts/4674b761/lib/form/section_.js HTTP/1.1" 200 903 "https://sub.   domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.   0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:20 +0800] "GET /jenkins/adjuncts/4674b761/lib/form/apply/apply.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1241 "https://sub.   domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.   0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:20 +0800] "GET /jenkins/adjuncts/4674b761/lib/form/confirm.js HTTP/1.1" 200 950 "https://sub.   domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.   0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  10.100.20.196 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:21 +0800] "GET /jenkins/login HTTP/1.1" 200 619 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:21 +0800] "GET /jenkins/adjuncts/4674b761/jenkins/management/AdministrativeMonitorsDecorator/   resources.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1110 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:28 +0800] "GET /jenkins/adjuncts/4674b761/jenkins/management/AdministrativeMonitorsDecorator/   resources.js HTTP/1.1" 200 959 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:30 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud/checkCloudName    HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:41 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud/   checkUseInstanceProfileForCredentials HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT    10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:41 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud/   checkAltEC2Endpoint HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:42 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/checkDescription    HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:42 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/checkLabelString    HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:42 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkIdleTerminationMinutes HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;    Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:42 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkMinimumNumberOfInstances HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;    Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:42 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkMinimumNumberOfSpareInstances HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.   0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:43 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkMinimumNoInstancesActiveTimeRangeFrom HTTP/1.1" 200 93 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0    (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:43 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkMinimumNoInstancesActiveTimeRangeTo HTTP/1.1" 200 93 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows    NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:44 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkInstanceCapStr HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:44 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/checkMonday HTTP/   1.1" 200 113 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:44 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkLaunchTimeoutStr HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:45 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkMaxTotalUses HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:45 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/org.jenkinsci.plugins.mailwatcher.   WatcherNodeProperty/checkOnlineAddresses HTTP/1.1" 200 54 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows    NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:45 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/org.jenkinsci.plugins.mailwatcher.   WatcherNodeProperty/checkOfflineAddresses HTTP/1.1" 200 54 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows    NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:45 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/checkDescription    HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:45 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkIdleTerminationMinutes HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;    Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:45 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/checkLabelString    HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:45 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkMinimumNumberOfInstances HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;    Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:45 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkMinimumNumberOfSpareInstances HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.   0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:45 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkMinimumNoInstancesActiveTimeRangeFrom HTTP/1.1" 200 93 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0    (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:45 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkMinimumNoInstancesActiveTimeRangeTo HTTP/1.1" 200 93 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows    NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:45 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkInstanceCapStr HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:45 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/checkMonday HTTP/   1.1" 200 113 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:45 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkLaunchTimeoutStr HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:45 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkMaxTotalUses HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:45 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud/   fillCredentialsIdItems HTTP/1.1" 200 131 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;    x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  10.203.40.50 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:46 +0800] "GET /jenkins/login HTTP/1.1" 200 619 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:46 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/org.jenkinsci.plugins.mailwatcher.   WatcherNodeProperty/checkOnlineAddresses HTTP/1.1" 200 54 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows    NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:46 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/checkDescription    HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:46 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/org.jenkinsci.plugins.mailwatcher.   WatcherNodeProperty/checkOfflineAddresses HTTP/1.1" 200 54 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows    NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:46 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud/   fillSshKeysCredentialsIdItems HTTP/1.1" 200 278 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;    Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:46 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   fillEbsEncryptRootVolumeItems HTTP/1.1" 200 152 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;    Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   fillConnectionStrategyItems HTTP/1.1" 200 155 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;    Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   fillHostKeyVerificationStrategyItems HTTP/1.1" 200 171 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT    10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   fillEbsEncryptRootVolumeItems HTTP/1.1" 200 152 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;    Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   fillHostKeyVerificationStrategyItems HTTP/1.1" 200 171 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT    10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   fillConnectionStrategyItems HTTP/1.1" 200 155 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;    Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   fillEbsEncryptRootVolumeItems HTTP/1.1" 200 152 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;    Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   fillConnectionStrategyItems HTTP/1.1" 200 155 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;    Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud/   fillCredentialsIdItems HTTP/1.1" 200 131 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;    x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   fillHostKeyVerificationStrategyItems HTTP/1.1" 200 171 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT    10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud/   fillSshKeysCredentialsIdItems HTTP/1.1" 200 278 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;    Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/checkLabelString    HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkIdleTerminationMinutes HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;    Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkMinimumNumberOfInstances HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;    Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkMinimumNumberOfSpareInstances HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.   0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkMinimumNoInstancesActiveTimeRangeFrom HTTP/1.1" 200 93 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0    (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkMinimumNoInstancesActiveTimeRangeTo HTTP/1.1" 200 93 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows    NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/checkMonday HTTP/   1.1" 200 113 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkInstanceCapStr HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkLaunchTimeoutStr HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkMaxTotalUses HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/org.jenkinsci.plugins.mailwatcher.   WatcherNodeProperty/checkOnlineAddresses HTTP/1.1" 200 54 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows    NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/org.jenkinsci.plugins.mailwatcher.   WatcherNodeProperty/checkOfflineAddresses HTTP/1.1" 200 54 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows    NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud/fillRegionItems    HTTP/1.1" 200 232 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkConnectionStrategy HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;    x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:47 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud/   checkSshKeysCredentialsId HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;    x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:48 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkHostKeyVerificationStrategy HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;    Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:48 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkConnectionStrategy HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;    x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:48 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkConnectionStrategy HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;    x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:48 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkHostKeyVerificationStrategy HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;    Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:48 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate/   checkHostKeyVerificationStrategy HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;    Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  123.456.789.101 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:48 +0800] "POST /jenkins/manage/descriptorByName/hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud/   checkSshKeysCredentialsId HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "https://sub.domain.com/jenkins/manage/configureClouds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;    x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  10.100.20.196 - - [09/Jan/2023:17:22:51 +0800] "GET /jenkins/login HTTP/1.1" 200 619 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
  ```

Other things that may be relevant:

- I'm running Jenkins version 2.375.1, installed via `yum install jenkins`.

Can anybody else confirm this issue, or is it only on my machine? What else can I check?

## Update

I figured out that a WAF ACL was blocking the HTTP request, causing HTTP 403 response. My bad.

Comment: Filed an issue related to this on Jira. See: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-70471

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no answer **why**, but to work around updating the *Configure Clouds* settings, I had to resort to the following:

1. SSH into the Jenkins controller.
2. Manually update `config.xml` in the `$JENKINS_HOME` directory.
3. Safe-restart Jenkins.